# How to check if user have X records from last 1 hour? [PHP/MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to check if the user has 5 records in my MySQL database in the last hour. That´s how I am doing it now:

```
$link = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM find_points WHERE timestamp > '.time()-3600.' AND user_id = '1' ORDER BY id DESC");

if(mysqli_num_rows($link) >= 5) {
   echo 'more than 5 results';
}
```

It looks like it should work, but it doesn't work...

Comment: While it's not the source of your issue, you may not want to override `$link` with a query result, as you may need that DB link later on. The *source* of your issue should be clear from the syntax highlighting. You've used the wrong quotes - `'.time()-3600.'` should be `".time()-3600."`. (Your code doesn't check for query errors. If it did, you'd get a nice clear syntax error back from MySQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query

```
SELECT * FROM find_points WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour,  timestamp , now() ) > 1  AND user_id = '1' ORDER BY id DESC
```

You can read in manual about [TimestampDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd)

It can be used to run difference between 2 dates in various formats.

Please check the Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a4d00/1)
It shows how TimestampDiff returns result and you can use the same in WHERE clause.

**Update**

Based on your comment, that the timestamp is stored as Unix Timestamp, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM find_points WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour,  FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) , now() ) > 1  AND user_id = '1' ORDER BY id DESC
```

`FROM_UNIXTIME` will convert your UNIX Timestamp to DateTime Format. You can then pass this to `TIMESTAMPDIFF` which will calculate difference and return the number of hours.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dereckkkk I have added SqlFiddle which shows how it works. Feel free to play with it.

Comment: @Dereckkkk Please create a SqlFiddle with table definition and some dummy data.

Comment: @Dereckkkk Updated Answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM find_points WHERE timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND user_id = '1' ORDER BY id DESC"